# Android - To play audio at 1.4 times the normal speed

Tags: android

I need to play mp3 at 1.4 (or other) times the normal speed. How can I do that?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SoundPool](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html) has a setRate method that does that.